# How do I use one XML node's prder to sort another?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Given two distinct nodes, how can I sort the second (product) using the order of the first (fruit) matching on the id?

```
<root>
    <fruit>
        <type id="3">Apple</type>
        <type id="32">Tomato</type>
        <type id="45">Pear</type>
        <type id="119">Pineapple</type>
    </fruit>

    <produce>
        <type id="45" location="aisle-five">Pear</type>
        <type id="3" location="aisle-one">Apple</type>
        <type id="119" location="aisle-seven">Pineapple</type>
        <type id="32" location="aisle-three">Tomato</type>
    </produce>
</root>
```

The XSLT would be some like this...

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root"> 
        <xsl:sort select="???" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/produce">
    <xsl:value-of select="type/@location" />
</xsl:template>
```

Desired output:

```
aisle-one
aisle-five
aisle-three
aisle-seven
```

This is a case where I don't have control of the XML, and only the second node is useful to me. As you may surmise, the actually data is mush more complex, but the concept is the same.

Comment: Provide desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Define a key

```
<xsl:key name="sort-key" match="/root/fruit[1]/type" use="."/>
```

and then your sort can be

```
<xsl:apply-templates match="produce">
  <xsl:sort select="key('sort-key', .)/@id" data-type="number"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I'm assuming you want to sort the type elements within a produce element, despite your code which appears to be trying to sort root elements.